# Telegram API Получение местоположение пользователя

Tags: telegram

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В Telegram можно получить местоположение пользователя двумя способами:

1. Отправить пользователю кнопку клавиатуры с параметром 'request_location'=>true. При нажатии на кнопку отправляются координаты пользователя
2. Пользователь прикрепляет координату с помощью "скрепки" и отправляет сообщение с координатой

Вопрос: существует ли способ проверки каким образом пользователь отправил координату, через кнопку или вручную?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)